# visual basic asp.net dropDownList not populating with values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, web-applications

I have an asp.net Visual Basic web site, and I am using a stored procedure to get values to populate a drop-down list.

However, I have two issues.  If I put the method to fill the drop-down list within my If Not IsPostBack statement in the page load event, then the whole list is filled with items saying 'System.Data.DataViewRow' instead of the actual values.  If I put it outside this 'if' statement but still in my page load event, I get the correct values, but no matter what I select, when I leave the drop-down it reverts back to the top item instead of the selected item.

What am I doing wrong??

Edit: I have now added the DataTextField as suggested by Nic and put the method inside my 'If Not IsPostBack' event as suggested by Lee Bailey.  However, my drop-down is still showing all values as 'System.Data.DataViewRow' so I don't know if Lee's solution has worked or not!  Any other ideas on the issue of showing the values!  I have updated my code below to reflect the changes.

The visual basic:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        bodyPanel.Visible = False
        drpRegion_fill()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub drpRegion_fill()
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
    sqlConn = New SqlConnection
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim drpRegionCmd As SqlCommand
    drpRegionCmd = New SqlCommand("getRegionName", sqlConn)
    drpRegionCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim drpRegionAdp As SqlDataAdapter
    drpRegionAdp = New SqlDataAdapter(drpRegionCmd)
    Dim drpRegionDs As DataSet
    drpRegionDs = New DataSet

    sqlConn.Open()
    drpRegionAdp.Fill(drpRegionDs)

    With drpRegion
        .DataSource = drpRegionDs
        .DataBind()
        .DataValueField = "regionName"
        .DataTextField = "regionName"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With

    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

The markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelRegion" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%" CssClass="inlineBlock">
<h2>Region:</h2>
<asp:dropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="drpRegion" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The SQL procedure returns a two-column dataset with 'regionID' as column 1, and 'regionName' as column2.

I've spent about two days on this now, trying various things and reading all the books I can!  I have never had this issue in C# when I have performed the same operation and I cannot for the life of me think what I've missed in the VB...

Comment: Does setting the DataTextField make a difference?

Comment: where do you set the DataTextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look as though you are setting the DataTextField property of your DropDownList:

```
 With drpRegion
        .DataSource = drpRegionDs
        .DataValueField = "regionName"
        .DataTextField = "fieldToDisplayAsText"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
        .DataBind()
 End With
```

source:
[MSDN DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx)

Comment: I've tried this but it hasn't resolved my issue, editing my original question to add updated code.

Comment: Did you set the DataTextField Property to the correct value ie a column name in your DataTable?

Comment: Yep - added info about the proc to my description too. regionName is the exact column name of the column I want displayed... :/

Comment: it is displaying the right number of rows however, so I'm clearly missing something else obvious...

Comment: In the MSDN example, the call to DataBind() is last. so try settin the DataFields first then call DataBind(). I will amend to reflect this.

Comment: No worries. Been a while since I've done asp.net. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

It's reverting back to the original value because you are re-binding the values to the dropdown after a postback. Changing the selected item  is triggering a postback because you have the AutoPostBack property set to true. I would call drpRegion_fill() only if it's not a postback. Setting the DataTextField as Ric mentioned should solve the problem regarding 'System.Data.DataViewRow'

Comment: Thank you - I've moved this within my 'If Not IsPostBack' section and will test now

Comment: I've moved the call to my 'If Not IsPostBack' section of the page_load event now but I'm not sure whether or not it's working because I now have the issue of all the items showing as System.Data.DataViewRow - despite the fact that I have also added the DataTextField property as recommended by Ric?  Will try and get round that then test...thank you!

Comment: This does work now that I have followed all advice from Ric - thank you so much!  I can only mark one as the answer though :/